# Is this the right way to expose sub-methods that I want to group logically in a class?

Tags: delphi

I have a base object, TCustomerDocument.  TCustomerDocument has two sets of addresses, home and business, that I could like to group logically as TCustomerDocument.HomeAddr and TCustomerDocument.BusinessAddr.  Then I can write code like MyCustomerDocument.HomeAddr.Line1 to read the first address line of the home address from the document.

The catch is that within TCustomerDocument those addresses are within another class (TDocumentHeader):

```
TCustomerDocument
  TDocumentHeader (address fields are in here)
```

Right now I can write

```
MyCustomerDocument.DocumentHeader.GetField('HOMEADDR1').AsString;
```

to access the first home address line.

Since TDocumentHeader will only ever have two addresses (home and business) I started with creating a TAddressInfo object:

```
TCustomerDocument
  Home: TAddressInfo
  Business: TAddressInfo
  TDocumentHeader (address fields are in here)
```

And this works just fine.  The relevant parts of the code are as follows:

```
type
TCustomerDocument = class; //fwd declaration

TAddressInfo = class(TObject)
private
    fDocumentHeader: TCustomerDocument;
    destructor Destroy; override;

public
    constructor Create(aCustomerDocument: TCustomerDocument);
    function Addr1: string;
end;

TCustomerDocument= class(TObject)
public
    HomeAddr: TAddressInfo;
    BusinessAddr: TAddressInfo
```

Then in TCustomerDocument.Create I have:

```
HomeAddr := TAddressInfo.Create(Self);
BusinessAddr := TAddressInfo.Create(Self);
```

[I've left out the cleanup/free code for brevity.]

I have no need (at this point) to access the TAddressInfo object directly - I just want to use this to group the fields logically to make my code clearer.

Question: Is this a correct way to structure the code to group those fields together or is there a simpler way (perhaps using a record structure within the class)?

Comment: It seems okay, although I'm missing some code (like freeing the address infos), of which I'm not sure whether you forgot it or you just left it out for brevity. Nevertheless, this seems to be a reasonable way of going.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I left out the freeing/cleanup code so nobody fell asleep before the end of the question. :-)

Comment: You have tightly bound your `TAddressInfo` class to your `TCustomerDocument` class which isn't good design practice. It makes it awkward for you to re-use the `TAddressInfo` class anywhere else. Remove the document reference from the class and you can get rid of the messy forward declaration as well.

Comment: @Andy_D, thank you.  Just to make sure I understand your comment (unsure of 'tightly bound') - you're suggesting that I should move TAddressInfo to its own unit?

Comment: By tightly bound I mean there is a dependency between the address and the document which doesn't need to be there (the reference to the document in the address class - imagine if a TButton had a reference to TForm) A good rule of thumb is to have one class per unit, but that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to what you want to do is to use properties in TCustomerDocument to  expose the Addresses within TCustomerDocument.DocumentHeader.

Something like this (from top of my head):

```
TAddress = Class(TObject)
private
  LineList: TStringlist;
  protected
    function GetLines(Index: Integer): string;
    procedure SetLines(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
  public
    property Lines[Index: Integer]: string read GetLines write SetLiines;

...
End;

  TCustomerDocumentHeader = class(TObject)
  public
    HomeAddress: TAddress;
    BusinessAddress: TAddress;
...
  end;

  TCustomerDocument = Class(TObject)
  private
    fDocumentHeader: TCustomerDocumentHeader;
    function GetBusinessAddress: TAddress;
    procedure SetBusinessAddress(const Value: TAddress);
    function GetHomeAddress: TAddress;
    procedure SetHomeAddress(const Value: TAddress);
...

  public
    Property DocumentHeader: TCustomerDocumentHeader read fDocumentHeader write fDocumentHeader;
    Property BusinessAddress: TAddress read GetBusinessAddress  write SetBusinessAddress;
    Property HomeAddress: TAddress read GetHomeAddress  write SetHomeAddress;
...
  End;
implementation

function TAddress.GetLines(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := LineList[Index];
end;

procedure TAddress.SetLines(Index: Integer; const Value: string);
begin
  LineList[Index] := Value;
end;


function TCustomerDocument.GetBusinessAddress: TAddress;
begin
  Result := DocumentHeader.BusinessAddress;
end;

function TCustomerDocument.GetHomeAddress: TAddress;
begin
  Result := DocumentHeader.HomeAddress;
end;

procedure TCustomerDocument.SetBusinessAddress(const Value: TAddress);
begin
  DocumentHeader.BusinessAddress := Value;
end;

procedure TCustomerDocument.SetHomeAddress(const Value: TAddress);
begin
  DocumentHeader.HomeAddress := Value;
end;
```

Then you can do things like

```
MyDocument.BusinessAddress.Lines[n] := '1 test street';
```

etc

Comment: thank you.  That makes good sense and that's the design that I was missing.